# Java RegEx - check if a string ends with an exact number of digits

Tags: java, regex, quantifiers

The Java matches method returns 'true' for all of the following

```
// check if a string ends with an exact number of digits (yyyyMMdd 8 digits)

    String s20180122_1 = "fileNamePrefix_20171219";
    String s20180122_2 = "fileNamePrefix_20171219131415111";

    System.out.println(s20180122_1.matches(".*\\d{8}$"));
    System.out.println(s20180122_2.matches(".*\\d{8}$"));
    System.out.println(s20180122_2.matches(".*\\d{8,8}$"));
```

Since the s20180122_2 has more digits I expect the 2nd and 3rd checks to return 'false', but they don't. How do I enforce the exact (8 digits only. No more, no less) match?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
.*[^\d]\d{8}$
```

or if Java regex engine supports `\D` group, you can use it instead of `[^\d]`

Comment: Very interesting. It works. Can you explain the logic please?

Comment: @badbee, the main issue with you regex that it doesn't set the left boundary of the digit part, which in your example is `_`. From your example you can use this regex: `.*_\d{8}$`. To make it a bit more generic you can use `[^\d]` (any character that is not a digit) instead of `_` character.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: This regex did not work as expected on oracle.  returned true with 9 digits.  Still working at it.  I actually want to test for ending in 6 or 8 digits.

Comment: This got it.  Couldn't edit my previous comment.  .*[:digit:{6|8}]$

Answer (score 1):

[This regex](https://regex101.com/r/EOA1zx/1) would validate that the last 8 characters are digits in `yyyyMMdd` form (and the year is within the 20th-21st centuries:

```
.*[^\d](19|20)\d{2}(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])$
```